# Display Google Analytics page view in specific page

Tags: php, google-api, google-oauth, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

i have stuck on displaying Google Analytics specific page view a few days, from referring on the [hello analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/web-js).

I have try to modify it to everybody can view without login gmail in specific web page(using autoload to taking accessToken), below are the code :

```
<?php 

session_start();
require_once 'google-api-php-client-2.2.1/vendor/autoload.php';


$accessToken = initializeAnalytics();

function initializeAnalytics()
{
  $KEY_FILE_LOCATION ='Testing-58a019909c51.json';

  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client -> setApplicationName("testing");
  $client -> setAuthConfig($KEY_FILE_LOCATION);
  $client -> setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']);
  $client -> refreshTokenWithAssertion();
  $client -> setAccessType("offline");
  $client -> setRedirectUri('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/testing-embed.php');
  $token = $client->getAccessToken();
  $accessToken = $token['access_token'];

  return $accessToken;

}

//echo $accessToken;

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>

<h1>View</h1>
<div id="test123"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
(function(w,d,s,g,js,fs){
  g=w.gapi||(w.gapi={});g.analytics={q:[],ready:function(f){this.q.push(f);}};
  js=d.createElement(s);fs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  js.src='https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
  fs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fs);js.onload=function(){g.load('analytics');};
}(window,document,'script'));
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">


gapi.analytics.ready(function() {

  /**
   * Authorize the user immediately if the user has already granted access.
   * If no access has been created, render an authorize button inside the
   * element with the ID "embed-api-auth-container".
   */
    gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
      'serverAuth': {
        'access_token': '<?php echo $accessToken ?>'
      }
    });

    function queryCoreReportingApi(profileId) {
        gapi.client.analytics.data.ga.get({
        'ids': 'ga:168634971',
        'start-date': '30daysAgo',
        'end-date': 'today',
        'metrics': 'ga:pageviews',
        'filters': 'ga:pagePath==/xxx'
        })
        .then(function(response) {
        var formattedJson = JSON.stringify(response.result, null, 2);
        var json = JSON.parse(formattedJson);
        var shares = parseInt(json.totalsForAllResults['ga:pageviews']);
        document.getElementById('test123').append(shares);
        })
        .then(null, function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
        }                 

});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

can anybody tell me what wrong of the code? Thanks for Help!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have access to the Google Analytics account in question the easest way to do this would be to use a service account rather than oauth2.   If you create service account credeitnals then take the service acccount email address and add it as a user in the admin section of google analytics at the account level it will have access to read from the Google Analytics api without requireing login

**Service account auth** [link to code](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-APIs-PHP-Samples/blob/master/Samples/Google%20Analytics%20Reporting%20API/v4/ServiceAccount.php)

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
// Use the developers console and download your service account
// credentials in JSON format. Place the file in this directory or
// change the key file location if necessary.
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='.__DIR__.'/service-account.json');
/**
 * Gets the Google client refreshing auth if needed.
 * Documentation: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount
 * Initializes a client object.
 * @return A google client object.
 */
function getGoogleClient() {
    return getServiceAccountClient();
}
/**
 * Builds the Google client object.
 * Documentation: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/service-accounts
 * Scopes will need to be changed depending upon the API's being accessed. 
 * array(Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_READONLY, Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS)
 * List of Google Scopes: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes
 * @return A google client object.
 */
function getServiceAccountClient() {
    try {   
        // Create and configure a new client object.        
        $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
        $client->addScope([YOUR SCOPES HERE]);
        return $client;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
session_start();
require_once __DIR__ . '/ServiceAccount.php';     
$client = getGoogleClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Analyticsreporting($client);
```

If you don't have access to add this user then you will need to work out saving the refresh token and reusing it.  I recommend saving it in a file on the server someplace but you will have an issue if the refresh token ever stops working which can happen.   I have a few samples on Oauth2 login with refresh token [here](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-APIs-PHP-Samples/tree/master/Samples/Google%20Analytics%20Reporting%20API/v4)

Comment: @DalmTo ask you saw at my question above, i have success to get the accessToken, just what i confuse are how do i use the accessToken to run the queryCoreReportingApi? Thank you

Comment: Access token is only good for one hour i assumed you were aware of that.  If you want it to work constantly without login you will need to save the refresh token and use the refresh token to request a new access token or use service accounts.  Other wise you are going to need to authenticate your code every hour.  Also you should not be using the access token to access the API you should be using your client to create Google_Service_Analyticsreporting as i have shown all requests will then be run though that.

Comment: @DalmTo i have tried the code for taking accessToken it still work after a few hour because of i set the accesstype to offline, now just a problem of showing my report.